# How to use current checked-out files as latest Branch?

Tags: windows-7, tortoisegit

I made a bunch of changes, reverted them, and ended up with my current working files being Headless.

How can set my current files as the latest version for the previous Head.

I tried Merging but got tons of conflicts and I didn't see a way to just let my current working files "win" all conflicts.

[image]

I'm working only locally, with very occasional updates to a repo @ github.  No other developers need to worry about changes made between gitub checkins.  (When another dev works on this they don't need to view the commit history)

Answer (score 1):

When your checked out revision has no branch then this is called detached HEAD and not HEADless... What do you mean by "make it new HEAD"? HEAD is defined to be the checked out revision. Also, what do you mean by "latest branch"?

I assume that you want to make your current HEAD your `master` branch, right? For this just (force) create a new branch on your HEAD revision and name it `master` - after that switch to it and force push your changes to your remote repository.

Please remember: A branch (or a tag) is just a label pointing to a revision (with all its history). So you can easily make it point to another revision by the steps I described in my above text.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all of the current file contents on top of your other branch, do a mixed reset on your other branch, checkout the branch and then commit your changes. Then you will have your current working tree as a new commit on top of your branch.

The mixed reset will just move the HEAD to your other branch but does not modify the index or the working tree contents.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to solve your situation:

## 1. Merge and Resolve Conflics

As you wrote you already know how to merge the two branches and you are getting lots of conflicts. In order to resolve the conflict use `TortoiseGit` → `Resolve...`

[image: ResolveConflict]

In the new window mark all files and click on `Resolve conflict using 'mine'` (the version of the file of your HEAD will be used).

For all details see [TortoiseGit Manual - Resolving Conflicts](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-conflicts.html)

## 2. Push with Option Force

In order to perform a push open the push dialog using `TortoiseGit` → `Push...`

[image: Push]

Select Ref and Destination Branches and use Option Force: May discard `unknown changes`.

For all details see [TortoiseGit Manual - Push](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-push.html)